# how to get all username member of the selected Voice Chanel to string in discord with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

hi guys i want code to get all member off my selected voice channel with id of voice channel
and get the username of members they are in the voice  channel of a server to a string variable and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// <client> is a placeholder for the client object
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<ID>'); // get channel

const usernames = channel.members.map(member => member.user.username); // get all members and map them by they're username

console.log(usernames.join('\n'));
```

---

[image: e1]

[image: e2]